# where is the best place to declare global variables, and checking something periodically?

Tags: omnet++, inet

my simulation consist of one mobile node and three access points, i want to detect the mobile nodes direction according to each access point, 
i know how to calculate it, but the position of mobile node will change by time...

I want to save last position of the mobile node before 1 second ago..or periodically check it every one second , the question is where is the best position to put my code that guarantee to execute every second....
second thing is which file of source codes is better to declare global variables?
any help highly appreciated...

Comment: As for your second question: You should post unrelated questions separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of periodic message scheduled which each node schedules to itself. Putting it in the final stages of `initialize()` is OK.

You can do something in the lines of:

```
void initialize(int stage)
{
    if (stage == 3)
    {
        cMessage *pMsg = new cMessage("myPeriodicMessage");
        scheduleAt(simTime()+1.0, pMsg);
    }
}
```

Then in the `handleMessage()` have:

```
void handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (msg->isSelfMessage())
    {
       /* if you have different selfMessages, compare them like below, or use different message kinds and checks accordingly */
       if (strcmp("myPeriodicMessage", msg->getName())==0)
       {
            doPeriodicTaks();
            scheduleAt(simTime()+1.0, pMsg);
       }
    }
}
```

Note that this way you will get the information you want separately for each node. If you want to have it in a centralized fashion, you should follow @Rudi's suggestion.

Comment: you did a great thing man, by your example code I completely understood how the periodic messages really work, before I couldn't estimate how they do working, by the way I must check the Rudi's suggestion, might it easier for me, if not I'll take your way , it can solve my problem.. again thanks for your prompt response...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using INET (which was not mentioned in your question):

The best place to store/calculate the velocity of your node is right inside the mobility module which already has a periodic update timer, but why do you need to calculate it at all? The `IMobility` interface already has `getCurrentAngularPosition()` and `getCurrentSpeed()` so you can get both the direction of the movement and the absolute value of the node speed any time you need, just like you can get the node's position. You should check whether the mobility model you are actually using implements these functions. If not, you should implement them there.

Comment: thanks for your explanation... you pointed to a great thing that I want actually, yes I must check the mobility module that already has a periodic timer, but my problem is I don't want velocity, I want to detect the mobile node's direction movement according to each access point at any time I want, Hence getCurrentAngularPosition() return what? I don't know the returned value is according to what?! I'm trying to capture last position of the node before some of time and get current position, then by those two points and the third one (AP) I can get direction of the node according to that AP.

Comment: since I am online I'll try to answer your questions. @Rudi please correct me if I am misleading somewhere. 

`getCurrentAngularPosition()` returns the angle of movement of a node based on a global coordinate system assumed to be laid all over the scenario. If you are looking only for direction of movement that information coming from `getCurrentAngularPosition()` is enough. But again, depends on your use case. For example, if you have two nodes moving in parallel on the same direction you might not be able to distinguish between the two.

Comment: as you mentioned above (getCurrentAngularPosition() returns the angle of movement of a node based on a global coordinate system assumed to be laid all over the scenario)as I see it doesn't useful for me, because I have one mobile node and three access points, I want to know the MN's movement direction according to each AP separately, for example may the MN has less direct to AP1 but vice-versa has more direct to AP2 while moving around ... Hence I think if there is a way to use getCurrentAngularPosition() to do that, its nice else I must try to do it by myself.  regards...